# Apoyo en Consulta SQL alguien?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, datos

Quiero mostrar el nombre de la columna (NombreResiduo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primer tabla esta relacionada con esta otra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta tercer tabla quiero relacionar la columna "Nombre" con la columna "NombreResiduo" de la primera tabla, la segunda tabla creo es la que las relaciona entre ambas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mi idea es relacionar ambas tablas antes mencionadas en una consulta SQL en la que masomenos se tiene que mostrar algo como abajo, mostrar dos columnas y en cada una mostrar los datos de nombre y nombre residuos, pero como se observa falta que muestre en la misma columna la primer tabla "NombreResiduo". En la misma columna, y aparte que este condicionada a que solamente determinado "IDcliente" muestre esa informacion.
Por ejemplo, solo el id CLiente "108" solo mostrara el campo "Baterias" y "Baterias de LITIO" ya que en el proyecto eson son los datos que estan asignadas a determinado usuario, Espero me haya dado a entender.
Aca un ejemplo de la consulta que hice, PEEEERO me muestra los datos de la primer tabla en todos los usuarios cuando deberia ser solo en uno mismo, por eso mencione que hay que condicionarlo.

```
SELECT rs.ID, rs.NombreResiduo FROM 137_dc_residuossitrasa AS rs 
UNION 
SELECT pr.IDCliente, pr.Nombre FROM 137_dc_perfilresiduos AS pr 
WHERE pr.IdCliente = 2
AND (estatus = 1 OR estatus = 2)
```

Comment: Ponle un título relevante y descriptivo a tu pregunta: lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta consulta poniendo en nombreTablaX el nombre de la tabla:

```
SELECT NombreResiduo, Nombre
FROM nombreTabla1 t1, nombreTabla2 t2, nombreTabla3 t3
WHERE t1.Clave = t2.IDResiduo AND t2.ID = t3.ID;
```

Esto te mostrará el campo 'NombreResiduo' junto los 'Nombre'.